# How can I filter and mark words from an input

Tags: html, javascript

I would like to filter and mark words from a page, something similar to the way Google marks words when you type a find query.

I am trying to do the filter and mark simultaneously. There are lots of solutions across the net that give examples of marking and examples of filtering but none that combine the two operations. Is this even possible?

I can show my filter script but not the marking script because I  simply can't find one that actually works. I would have to upload dozens of scripts that I have tried.

Can anyone assist in pointing me in the right direction or even better maybe help with a snippet that actually works.

I can't believe it is so difficult to find.

This works wonderfully to filter the words or phrase but it does not mark it in the paragraph.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myDIV` contains elements only one layer deep, the following code should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myDIV>*").map(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            var content = el.html().replace(/(<span class="highlighted">)|(<\/span>)/g, "");
            el.html(content);
            var hasText = el.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
            el.toggle(hasText);
            if (hasText) {
                // escape value for use in regex
                var textRegex = new RegExp(value.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&"), "g");
                el.html(content.replace(textRegex, '<span class="highlighted">$&</span>'));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" />
<div id="myDIV">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some filler</p>
  <p>I like cheese</p>
  <p>this should work</p>
</div>
```